# How do I give a watson chatbot an Android front end?

Tags: watson-conversation

How do I give a watson chatbot an Android front end?

I've built an IBM Watson chatbot and I've built an android messaging app.
Now I'd like to connect the two.

I'm wondering how to do it.
I guess I'll make API calls.
Does anyone have some sample code that I can look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watson Developer cloud can be accessed using REST API's.

There is also an SDK for android available.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk